# Detect location by IP address (I get a blank page. Why?)

Tags: php, ip

Here is an useful code snippet to detect the location of a specific IP address. The function below takes one IP address as a parameter, and returns the location of the IP address. If no location is found, UNKNOWN is returned.

But I get a blank page. Why?

```
function detect_city($ip) {
    $default = 'UNKNOWN';

    if (!is_string($ip) ||
        strlen($ip) < 1 ||
        $ip == '127.0.0.1' ||
        $ip == 'localhost')

        $ip = '8.8.8.8';

    $curlopt_useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2)      Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)';

    $url = 'http://ipinfodb.com/ip_locator.php?ip=' . urlencode($ip);
    $ch = curl_init();

    $curl_opt = array(
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER      => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT   => $curlopt_useragent,
        CURLOPT_URL       => $url,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 1,
        CURLOPT_REFERER         => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_opt);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!is_null($curl_info)) {
        $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    if ( preg_match('{<li>City : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs) )  {
        $city = $regs[1];
    }
    if ( preg_match('{<li>State/Province : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs) )  {
        $state = $regs[1];
    }

    if ( $city!='' && $state!='' ) {
        $location = $city . ', ' . $state;
        return $location;
    }
    else {
        return $default;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call this method? Please, show full code source.

Comment: Instead of messing with page scraping you should consider using their API http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php .  php code is provided and the user key is free.

Comment: thanks  @ fvu i use this source and work fine but i just need to show my only countryCode what can do that for this ?!

Answer (score 3):

You probably get a blank page because there is an error in your script and PHP is not configured to display errors, which is the case on most online webspaces. Try to enable error display by adding this to a `.htaccess` file in the same directory:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if (!is_null($curl_info)) {
    $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
}
```

The **$curl_info** does not exist and `cannot be` by seeing your parameters and the rest code above. Instead, comment the `if` out and you should be fine (tested on my IP address):

```
// if (!is_null($curl_info)) {
   $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
// }
```

Comment: i get blank page again  can you post the complete cod that you tested on your ip?!

Comment: the very same code, just commented those 2 lines.. but you can enable error reporting to see if you have problems:  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors",1); in very top of your page... You can also check if $content actually contains anything (echo $content) before preg_match it..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

```
function detect_city($ip) {

    $default = 'UNKNOWN';

    if (!is_string($ip) || strlen($ip) < 1 || $ip == '127.0.0.1' || $ip == 'localhost')
        $ip = '8.8.8.8';

    $curlopt_useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)';

    $url = 'http://ipinfodb.com/ip_locator.php?ip=' . urlencode($ip);
    $ch = curl_init();

    $curl_opt = array(
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER      => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT   => $curlopt_useragent,
        CURLOPT_URL       => $url,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 1,
        CURLOPT_REFERER         => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_opt);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!is_null($curl_info)) {
        $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    if ( preg_match('{<li>City : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs) )  {
        $city = $regs[1];
    }
    if ( preg_match('{<li>State/Province : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs) )  {
        $state = $regs[1];
    }

    if( $city!='' && $state!='' ){
      $location = $city . ', ' . $state;
      return $location;
    }else{
      return $default; 
    }

}
```